# How to rewrite webRequestBlocking into declarativeNetRequest for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to convert an extension written using `webRequestBlocking` permission to `declarativeNetRequest`.

Lets say, my rules regex is like:

`const youtubeAdRegexesFallback = ["(doubleclick.net)","(adservice.google.)","(youtube.com/api/stats/ads)","(&ad_type=)","(&adurl=)","(-pagead-id.)","(doubleclick.com)","(/ad_status.)","(/api/ads/)","(/googleads)","(/pagead/gen_)","(/pagead/lvz?)","(/pubads.)","(/pubads_)","(/securepubads)","(=adunit&)","(googlesyndication.com)","(innovid.com)","(youtube.com/pagead/)","(google.com/pagead/)","(flashtalking.com)","(googleadservices.com)","(s0.2mdn.net/ads)","(www.youtube.com/ptracking)","(www.youtube.com/pagead)","(www.youtube.com/get_midroll_)"]`

and I just need to block these:
`"script", "image", "xmlhttprequest", "sub_frame"`

So, I wrote a JS function to do it for me like this:

```
const youtubeAdRegexesFallback = ["(doubleclick.net)","(adservice.google.)","(youtube.com/api/stats/ads)","(&ad_type=)","(&adurl=)","(-pagead-id.)","(doubleclick.com)","(/ad_status.)","(/api/ads/)","(/googleads)","(/pagead/gen_)","(/pagead/lvz?)","(/pubads.)","(/pubads_)","(/securepubads)","(=adunit&)","(googlesyndication.com)","(innovid.com)","(youtube.com/pagead/)","(google.com/pagead/)","(flashtalking.com)","(googleadservices.com)","(s0.2mdn.net/ads)","(www.youtube.com/ptracking)","(www.youtube.com/pagead)","(www.youtube.com/get_midroll_)"]

var id = 1
var finalRegexArr = []
youtubeAdRegexesFallback.forEach((item)=> {
    finalRegexArr.push({
        "id": id++,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "condition": {
            "regexFilter": item,
            "domains" : ["youtube.com"],
            "resourceTypes": [
                "script", "image", "xmlhttprequest", "sub_frame"
            ]
        }
    })
})

copy(finalRegexArr)
```

and added the rules in the manifest like this by adding them in a file named `ruleset_yt.json`:

```
"declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_yt",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "ruleset_yt.json"
      }
    ]
  }
```

But still, some ads are showing. How to fix it?

Comment: Since the conversion is straightforward and trivial, the problem must be elsewhere, it can also be a bug in Chrome. Inspect the stray ads and see what's different about them, check their URLs, check where they appear, see if their requests go through an iframe that has a `google.com` address. P.S. for efficiency use just one rule with regexFilter: youtubeAdRegexesFallback.join('|'), remove `()` around each value, and replace each `.` with `\\.`.

Comment: Tried so many ways but still its showing ads. But the main extension which I'm trying to port ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-for-youtube/cmedhionkhpnakcndndgjdbohmhepckk?hl=en ) it works absolutely fine. Is there any other resources to do this? I mean, to port this extension to iOS 15 safari without using persistent background and using declarativeNetRequest instead of webRequestBlocking or webRequest? Thanks

Comment: My comment already describes what may be wrong so your first step might be, for example, to remove `"domains" : ["youtube.com"],` and don't forget to reinstall/reload the extension.

Comment: Okay, let me try with the suggestions you mentioned. Thanks btw

Comment: Just one question: Lets say I've successfully created the rules. So, now don't I need any kind of background.js file? Just the manifest and the rules would be enough? Thanks